# add page headers to roxygen2 docs

Tags: roxygen2, rd

I'm using roxygen2 to document the objects in  my R package, as described in the book [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html). I want to insert some text at the top (and bottom) of the doc page for every object, saying for example, "Confidential - Do Not Release". For the HTML doc pages I could do that with a CSS `content` property, or by inserting some HTML of course.

So how can I modify the page headings of the doc pages rendered from roxygen2?  For now I'm only interested in the HTML doc pages, not PDF, so it might be enough to insert some arbitrary CSS or HTML into every doc page with roxygen2, or Rd. Is that possible?

Ideally I'd like to find an option that I can set once globally for the whole package, since if I have to add it separately to each object's documentation, I may miss some. But if I have to add it to each object, I can live with it.